# Custom Policy stable-baselines3

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, policy, stable-baselines, actor-critics

I'm trying to create a custom Policy for A2C with `stable-baselines3`, but I'm stuck. I'm using a MultiBinary observation space (80x80 grid) and continuous actions.

```
 self.action_space = Box(
            low=-1.0, high=1.0, shape=(4,), dtype=np.float32)
        self.observation_space = MultiBinary(
            [self.row_col_length, self.row_col_length])
```

I've tried to use `CnnPolicy` directly, but that only seems to work with images, so I decided to create a custom policy.

```
from typing import Callable, Dict, List, Optional, Tuple, Type, Union

import gym
import torch as th
from torch import nn

from stable_baselines3 import PPO
from stable_baselines3.common.policies import ActorCriticPolicy
from torchsummary import summary


class CustomNetwork(nn.Module):
    
    def __init__(
        self,
        last_layer_dim_pi: int = 64,
        last_layer_dim_vf: int = 64,
    ):
        super(CustomNetwork, self).__init__()

        self.latent_dim_pi = last_layer_dim_pi
        self.latent_dim_vf = last_layer_dim_vf

        # Policy network
        self.policy_net = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(1, 64, kernel_size=5), #returns 76 (80-5+1)
            nn.Tanh(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2), # 76/2=38
            nn.Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=5), #returns 34 (38-5+1)
            nn.Tanh(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2), #34/2=17
            nn.Flatten(start_dim=0),
            nn.Linear(64*17*17, last_layer_dim_pi),
            nn.Tanh()
        )
        # Value network
        self.value_net = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(1, 64, kernel_size=5), #returns 76 (80-5+1)
            nn.Tanh(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2), # 76/2=38
            nn.Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=5), #returns 34 (38-5+1)
            nn.Tanh(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2), #34/2=17
            nn.Flatten(0),
            nn.Linear(64*17*17, last_layer_dim_vf),
            nn.Tanh()
        )

    def forward(self, features: th.Tensor) -> Tuple[th.Tensor, th.Tensor]:
        """
        :return: (th.Tensor, th.Tensor) latent_policy, latent_value of the specified network.
            If all layers are shared, then ``latent_policy == latent_value``
        """
        device = features.device
        if features.shape[1] == 6400: #do this for the first layer only
            features = features.reshape(features.shape[0], 80, 80).to(device)
            return self.forward_actor(features), self.forward_critic(features)
        return self.forward_actor(features), self.forward_critic(features)
    
    def forward_actor(self, features: th.Tensor) -> th.Tensor:
        print(f'\n\nFeatures {features.shape}\n\n')
        device = features.device
        if features.shape[1] == 6400: #do this for the first layer only
            reshaped_features = features.reshape(1, 80, 80).to(device)
            return self.policy_net(reshaped_features)
        return self.policy_net(features)

    def forward_critic(self, features: th.Tensor) -> th.Tensor:
        device = features.device
        if features.shape[1] == 6400: #do this for the first layer only
            print(f'\n\nFeatures {features.shape}\n\n')
            reshaped_features = features.reshape(features.shape[0], 80, 80).to(device)
            return self.value_net(reshaped_features)
        
        return self.value_net(features)
       

class CustomActorCriticPolicy(ActorCriticPolicy):
    def __init__(
        self,
        observation_space: gym.spaces.Space,
        action_space: gym.spaces.Space,
        lr_schedule: Callable[[float], float],
        net_arch: Optional[List[Union[int, Dict[str, List[int]]]]] = None,
        activation_fn: Type[nn.Module] = nn.Tanh,
        *args,
        **kwargs,
    ):

        super(CustomActorCriticPolicy, self).__init__(
            observation_space,
            action_space,
            lr_schedule,
            net_arch,
            activation_fn,
            # Pass remaining arguments to base class
            *args,
            **kwargs,
        )
        # Disable orthogonal initialization
        self.ortho_init = False

    def _build_mlp_extractor(self) -> None:
        device = "cuda" if th.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"
        self.mlp_extractor = CustomNetwork()
        self.mlp_extractor.to(device)
```

The problem is it's giving me a RunTime error that has to do with the channels: `RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [64, 1, 5, 5], expected input[1, 5, 80, 80] to have 1 channels, but got 5 channels instead`.

PS: The `reshape` is necessary because the observations come in (1, 6400) instead of (1, 80, 80). I'm assuming this happens because it's an MLP, and not an image.
Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?